# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.action.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, maven

used: hibernate 3.6.2, maven 2, postgres 9.
I have code that must work but it doesn't. When I launch functional test I've got the error:

java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.action.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Code is a standart domain model:

Entity:

```
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
@Entity
@Table(schema = "simulators", name = "mySimulator_card")
public class MySimulatorCard {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "account_number", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String accountNumber;
```

etc...

DAO:

```
public abstract class AbstractDao<E, PK extends Serializable> implements Dao<E, PK> {

    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return entityManager;
    }

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "MySimulator")
    public void setEntityManager(EntityManager entityManager) {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    public abstract Class<E> getEntityClass();

    @Override
    public void persist(E e) {
        getEntityManager().persist(e);
    }

    @Override
    public E merge(E e) {
        return getEntityManager().merge(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void refresh(E e) {
        getEntityManager().refresh(e); //<-- some thing wroooong
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(E e) {
        getEntityManager().remove(e);
    }
```

etc...

And according table:

```
CREATE TABLE simulators.mySimulator_card
(
  id bigserial NOT NULL,
  account_number character varying(255) NOT NULL,

etc...

  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_card_pk PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_card_account_fk FOREIGN KEY (account_id)
      REFERENCES simulators.mySimulator_account (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_card_currency_fk FOREIGN KEY (currency_id)
      REFERENCES simulators.mySimulator_currency ("name") MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_card_product_fk FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
      REFERENCES simulators.mySimulator_product (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_account_account_number_uq UNIQUE (account_number),
  CONSTRAINT mySimulator_card_san_uq UNIQUE (san)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE simulators.mySimulator_card OWNER TO functional;
```

Here are stack trace till my code:

```
 at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.LongTypeDescriptor.unwrap(LongTypeDescriptor.java:36)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:52)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:91)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:282)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:277)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindPositionalParameters(Loader.java:1873)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.bindParameterValues(Loader.java:1844)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1716)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:801)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2037)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
        at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3293)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:151)
        at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultRefreshEventListener.onRefresh(DefaultRefreshEventListener.java:62)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireRefresh(SessionImpl.java:1118)
        at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.refresh(SessionImpl.java:1098)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:738)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.refresh(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:713)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
        at $Proxy153.refresh(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
        at $Proxy82.refresh(Unknown Source)
        at com.goooogle.simulator.mysimulator.dao.AbstractDao.refresh(AbstractDao.java:42)
```

Why? Is it hibernate's bug?

Answer (score 1):

I had faced exactly same exception when doing a save(). I solved it by correcting the cascade option in the hibernate mapping file. I changed it from "all-delete-orphan,save-update, delete "to "save-update, delete, delete-orphan" and it worked for me.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

This exception baffled me just today and happened in a Spring Boot application using the JpaRepository.

In my case this occured when a `JpaRepostitory.findBySomeEntity` was called. *SomeEntity* had been saved in the same transaction using `JpaRepository.save(...)` rather than `JpaRepository.saveAndFlush(...)`. Therefore its ID was not yet set.

Looks like Hibernate is trying to substitute the missing entity id with the `DelayedPostInsertIdentifier` created in the uncommitted save-transaction even though it can't be cast to the id-type.

It's a misleading Exception. Good thing it was easily fixed by the `saveAndFlush(...)`.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I used Panache and the syntax was just a bit different `persistAndFlush` but it was it

Answer (score 0):

Is your driver and dialect correct in your hibernate.properties file?

hibernate.connection.driver_class = org.postgresql.Driver

hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#configuration-hibernatejdbc

Comment: dialect was provided, driver_class was not provided. I add row  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/> but it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define your primary key as IDENTITY on your create table statement.

```
id bigserial NOT NULL IDENTITY
```

Comment: I'm not a guru in postgres but there is no keyword identity in postgreSQL, so I can't use your example.

Comment: try creating a sequence.

CREATE SEQUENCE sq;
CREATE TABLE t_test(
 id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT NEXTVAL('sq'),
 name VARCHAR(10)
 );
INSERT INTO t_test(name)
 VALUES ('Andrew');
INSERT INTO t_test(name)
 VALUES ('Gordon');
SELECT * FROM t_test;

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question was asked pretty while ago, but there is no answer for my case and I had to deal it myself.

So in my case the issue was in Parent-child Entity relations, I defined non-nullable join column as `@JoinColumn(nullable = false)` and Hibernate could not insert child Entity without knowing parent ID. Throwing me `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.action.internal.DelayedPostInsertIdentifier cannot be cast to class java.lang.Long`.

So the fix was in setting `@JoinColumn` as nullable.

My parent Entity was:

```java
@Entity
public class Quiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id", nullable = false)
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Question.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public List<Question> questionList;
}
```

And my child Entity was:

```java
@Entity
public class Question {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;
}
```

And the fixed Parent Entity:

```java
@Entity
public class Quiz {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "quiz_id")
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, targetEntity = Question.class)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    public List<Question> questionList;
}
```

Logically I understand that this was my fault, since it's not possible to insert non-nullable ID when you don't know it, but Hibernate could thrown better, not so confusing, exception.

And yes, after the fix Hibernate issues additional Entity update to set parent ID:

```
DEBUG [org.hib.SQL] insert into Quiz (user_name) values ($1) returning id
DEBUG [org.hib.SQL] insert into Question (question) values ($1) returning id
DEBUG [org.hib.SQL] update Question set quiz_id=$1 where id=$2
```